# Advantage of Button over TextView with Selector

Tags: android, button, textview

I was looking at the documentation for the Button widget and noticed that it is a subclass of TextView. Is there any real difference between a Button and a TextView if I use the same selector drawable on both. In other words, I already am using TextViews with selectors for my app's "buttons", but is there anything to be gained from using the Button class instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's essentially no difference between `TextView` and `Button`.  `Button` just comes styled as a button out of the box.

Here is the source for `Button` from API 19.

```
@RemoteView
public class Button extends TextView {
    public Button(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
    }
}
```